# How should I solve $\left\{x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\left\{x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right\}u\left(x,y\right)=u$

$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=u$

Let's solve for

$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{\left(y+x^2\right)}$

$y=x^2+Cx$

$\frac{y-x^2}{x}=C$

$u=\Phi \left(\frac{y-x^2}{x}\right)$

But that's just if it's = 0, so I don't know what to do if that's = u or something else...

Answer (score 1):

A general solution using the method of characteristics is
$$ u = x\;  \Phi \left( \frac{y-x^2}{x}\right) $$

EDIT: 
The characteristic curves are $(y-x^2)/x = c$, as you essentially found.  Along one of these curves, parametrized as $x = t$, $y = t^2 + c t$, we have

$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{d}{dt} u(t, t^2+ct) &=  \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,t^2+ct) +  (2 t + c) \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(t,t^2+ct)\cr &=  \left.\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{y+x^2}{x} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right|_{x=t,y=t^2+ct}\cr &= \left. \frac{1}{x} \left( x \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + (y+x^2) \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)\right|_{x=t,y=t^2+ct}\cr &= \frac{u(t,t^2+ct)}{t}}$$
The general solution of $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{v}{t}$ is
$ v = C t $.
Since the "constant" $C$ depends on which characteristic curve it is, i.e. on $c = (y-x^2)/x$, and $t = x$ on the curve, we get the solution
$$ u(x,y) = x\; \Phi\left( \frac{y-x^2}{x}\right) $$

Comment: Could you please show me how you came to this solution?

Comment: Aha, so you make this substitution, then you declare v(t)=u(....) and simply take the derivative with respect to t and after that you'll change it back to x and y so you can see how it relates to v and t in the end? And then if you calculate this differential equation with v and t, you basically just have to change v for u and C for this phi(...) and t to x back again? Does this kind of substitution always work? How should I know which substitution I should take?

Answer (score 0):

Giving

$$
u_h(x,y) = \Phi\left(\frac{y-x^2}{x}\right)
$$

now making a change of variables

$$
\cases{a = x\\
b=\frac{y-x^2}{x}}
$$

on

$$
x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\left(y+x^2\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=u
$$

we get at

$$
u = a \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}
$$

with solution

$$
u(a,b) = a\Phi(b)
$$

Comment: Can you maybe show me how did you get to u = a (du/da) ?

Comment: And also, more important, why id (du/da) equal to phi(b) ?

Comment: The reduction to $u = a u_a$ is obtained by a simple use of the chain rule plus some substitutions and $u=a\Phi(b)$ is the solution for $u = a u_a$

Comment: How should it be the solution? If I try to solve u=a (du/da) I'll get du/u = da/a which is ln|u| = ln|a| (ignoring the constant) thus u=a

Comment: You can't ignore the constant. The solution gives $u=aC(b)$ where $C(b)$ is your "constant".

Comment: And why should C(b) be equal to Phi(b)? Or is it something we can assume because in the end it all just depends on b?

Comment: $C(b)$ is a **generic** $b$ function. It can be called $\Phi,\Psi,\Omega$ etc. This function can be defined after the boundary conditions.

Comment: Ok, understand. But this kind of substitution you do here, can it be applied to any exercise of this kind?

Comment: Note that we are solving a PDE and not a ODE. This is the main reason to consider $C(b)$ and not $C_0$